# How do I create this class (involving indexer properties?)

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with C#.NET and basically have a page containing many areas.

In my code-behind, I basically want to be able to do something like:

```
bool result1 = MyClass.Section["area1"].Process();
bool result4 = MyClass.Section["area4"].Process();
```

I need to write a class that would call some kind of "`Process`" method and be able to have it accept a parameter like "`area1`" inside that method.

Any help on getting me started with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you have to have a class that has `Process`.

Answer (score 1):

Following the normal .NET naming conventions I'll assume you mean, by your example, that `MyClass` is being referenced statically rather than by instance (which may not be a big change). Given that assumption, it appears you have a class like:

```
static class MyClass
{
    public static IIndexer Section { get; } 
}
```

`IIndexer` in this case could be any type that implements an indexer property that takes a string and returns a type that has a method named `Process` which in turn returns a `bool`. `IIndexer` could theoretically look like:

```
interface IIndexer
{
    ISomething this[string] { get; }
}
```

Next we'll fill in the `ISomething` blank above with a simple `IProcess` interface so we don't have to know anything about your specific implementation:

```
interface IProcess
{
    bool Process();
}
```

So now the indexer above can be changed to:

```
IProcess this[string] { get; }
```

Of course, none of the above has any real executable code, but outlines the objects necessary to do what you're after. Now when you go to run your code using your fulfilled contracts the call chain is pretty simple:

```
bool result1 = MyClass.Section["area1"].Process();
// MyClass.Section > IIndexer.this[string] > IProcess.Process
```

To POC the idea, a good way to mock the IIndexer implementation might be to use `Dictionary<string, IProcess>` as it'll give you a usable indexer for your purposes.

Comment: Since IProcess is an interface, where can I implement the Process method? Do I need to create a separate class? Also, what do I put for the return statement in the getter for "public static IIndexer Section"?

Comment: 1) Yes you will need to write an implementation of `IProcess` containing the actual logic you want to perform. 2) Return whatever type contains the indexer property. Without getting deeper into your implementation it would be hard to know what that is exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this M.Babcock. My last questions.. I don't want to write a separate class to implement IProcess because I want my static class "MyClass" to be able to use that method? Can you also show me a sample of how to utilize the Dictionary<string, IProcess> in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve or why you would want to enforce such a pattern on your design, but the only solutions the come to mind would alter your target invocation pattern to something like `bool result1 = MyClass.Section["area1"];` or possibly more confusingly `bool result1 = MyClass.Section["area1"]();`. These are possible. but, to match your requested invocation style, you'll need some concrete class to do the heavy lifting.